# Windows 8.1 - Right click very slow only the first time

Tags: windows-8.1

I have windows 8.1 , and the first time I try to right click  file or folder , it need a lots of time. 
But after , other times the right click works very well.
I try shellEx , but I don't see any problematic entries.
And why that happen only the first time ?
Thank you !

Comment: it might be an issue with a Hardware , like Hard Drive Disk.

Comment: It's a new pc , just purchased.

Comment: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/slow-right-click-context-menu/ Try this

Comment: Try it in safe mode, and if it doesn't hang on the first click like you're explaining, then it's some 3rd party utility that's doing it (most likely).